# Is there a clean API for resetting instance variables on 'reload' in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In an `ActiveRecord::Base` model, I can reset the state of the model to what it was when I got it from the database with `reload`, as long as the attribute I'm setting maps to a table column:

```
user = User.first
user.email #=> "email@domain.com"
user.email = "example@site.com"
user.email #=> "example@site.com"
user.reload
user.email #=> "email@domain.com"
```

But if I add a custom attribute, the only way I've found to have it act the same is like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :user_agent

  def reload
    super
    self.user_agent = nil
    self
  end
end
```

My question is, is there some API to make non-database-column-attributes reset on reload? Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this
  reloadable_attr_accessor :user_agent
  # or this
  def user_agent
    @user_agent
  end

  def user_agent=(value)
    set_instance_var_that_resets_on_reload("@user_agent", value)
  end
end
```

Does that exist in Rails somewhere?

Comment: +1. I wish the rails team would provide a cleaner way to hook virtual attributes into AR models lifecyle. Maybe we could suggest them to do so ? I could really see a `virtual_attribute` macro, that would take care of reload issues and dirtyness.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ActiveRecord does not provide a way to do this, it can only acts on the model attributes.

That being said, I think a more elegant way to do it would be to loop over the ivars and set them to whatever you like :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reload(options = nil)
    super
    self.instance_variables.each do |ivar|
      next if ivar == '@attributes'
      self.instance_variable_set(ivar, nil)      
    end
  end
 end
```

Note that we skip @attributes because AR is taking care of it when you reload the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But it makes all associations nil as well :(

Comment: doesn't rails provide a not such ugly way to reset all attributes ? :/

Answer (score 6):

Rework Jean-Do's answer slightly. It doesn't break default instance_variables and relations.

```
after_initialize do 
  @default_instance_variables = instance_variables
end

def reload(options = nil)
  super
  self.instance_variables.each do |ivar|
    if ivar == :'@default_instance_variables' || 
      @default_instance_variables.include?(ivar)
      next 
    end
    remove_instance_variable(ivar)
  end
  self
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I took gayavat's answer and reworked it into my `test_helper.rb` file, because I didn't want to override the usual #reload method.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :default_instance_variables
  after_initialize do 
    @default_instance_variables = instance_variables
  end
end
def reload_ivars(obj)
  obj.reload
  obj.instance_variables.each do |ivar|
    if ivar == :'@default_instance_variables' || 
     obj.default_instance_variables.include?(ivar)
      next 
    end
    obj.send(:remove_instance_variable, ivar)
  end
end
```

When I need to reload something in a test I just call `reload_ivars(object)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked gavayat's answer slightly. I've made three changes:

- Using a class variable to store `default_instance_variables` makes a bit more sense here (unless you're conditionally instantiating instance variables in your constructor, but you don't want to do that). This way you don't need to check for `default_instance_variables` itself inside `reload`.
- I've moved the `super` call to the end of the function. This ensures that this method returns whatever `ActiveRecord::Base.reload` returns, and gets rid of a line of code.
- The options parameter is actually passed into the `super` call.

```rb
after_initialize do 
  @@default_instance_variables ||= instance_variables
end

def reload(options = nil)
  self.instance_variables.each do |ivar|
    if @@default_instance_variables.include?(ivar)
      next 
    end
    remove_instance_variable(ivar)
  end
  super(options)
end
```