# Rails, ActiveRecord: Callback run during #reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with an attribute that is generated from the values of the persisted column values.

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :records, through: :job

  def processed_records
    @processed_records ||=
      begin
        status_flagged + status_invalid +
          status_unknown + status_valid
      end
  end
end
```

My problem is that the Result object sometimes has to call #reload to get new values from the DB. Is there a callback I can hook into to clear the value of `@processed_records`, so that the next call will re-compute the value?

In other words, I'd like this to work:

```
RSpec.describe Result, :type => :model do
  subject { create(:result) }

  it 'should update #processed_records on reload' do
    initial_value = subject.processed_records

    other_instance = Result.find(subject.id)
    other_instance.increment(:status_flagged)
    other_instance.save

    subject.reload
    expect(subject.processed_records).to eq(initial_value + 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: `def reload; super; @processed_records = nil; end` ?

Comment: Give a try to `after_find`

Comment: @MarianTheisen Yeah, that would work... I was just hoping for something a bit more semantically relevant, along the lines of `after_update`.

Comment: @Aguardientico Unfortunately, `after_find` is called on a new instance, before it is initialized, which is not the case on the object being reloaded.

Comment: @slushie Did you do the test? It works for me, every time I do a reload the after_find is called.

Comment: @Aguardientico Yes, it is called. But it's called on a new instance, not on the existing one. I added a few `puts` in to be sure: `#<Result:0x007f9db815ccc0>#processed_records
#<Result:0x007f9db832cd70>#after_find_callback
#<Result:0x007f9db833d0d0>#after_find_callback
#<Result:0x007f9db815ccc0>#processed_records
`

Comment: Gotcha so @MarianTheisen is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602443/is-there-a-clean-api-for-resetting-instance-variables-on-reload-in-activerecor

Comment: def reload; @processed_records = nil; super; end -> reload returns a reference on itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the `reload` method in your model:

```
def reload
  super

  # code with whatever you need to clean, for example:
  @processed_records = nil
end
```

Comment: Good idea, I'd recommend call `super` as last line in the method though, in order to keep the original return value and support chaining things (e.g. `result.reload.processed_records`)