# How to fully reload an ActiveRecord to reset it's memoized values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

In an RSpec test, I create a record that has several memoizied values.

`foo.reload` works as expected for the object's attributes, but memoized ones are still present.

So far, it works by completely recreating the object: `foo = Foo.find(123)` but in my case, the logic for finding the record is actually more complex.

What's a good, DRY way to fully reload the record and erase all memoized values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The good way is the one you already have: Completely recreating the object.

You cannot "reload" the object's memoized values in any easy "Rails" way, as memoizing attributes isn't a function of Rails or ActiveRecord. Neither knows anything about how you're memoizing methods.

Comment: It is still the case in 2016 ?

Comment: Is that still a case in 2017? Can we somehow memoize until first reload?

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by redefining `reload`. For example if you memoized with `||=` you can do that:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def bar
    @bar ||= rand
  end

  def reload(options = nil)
    @bar = nil
    super
  end
end
```

For ways to reset all instance variables see [Is there a clean API for resetting instance variables on 'reload' in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602443/is-there-a-clean-api-for-resetting-instance-variables-on-reload-in-activerecor)

If you use the [memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) gem you can call `flush_cache` there.

Answer (score 4):

Michael's answer is sound, but be aware that if you use [the more sophisticated pattern for also memoization `nil` and `false` values](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/), that will NOT reset the memoization.

For instance, using the same example from the article for memoization `nil` and `false` values:

```rb
def main_address
  return @main_address if defined? @main_address
  @main_address = begin
    main_address = get_home_address_from_api
    main_address ||= get_work_address_from_api
    main_address ||= another_api_call.first
  end
end
```

This pattern works great because it also memoizes `nil` and `false`, but of course, to reset it, it wouldn't be enough to simply set the `@main_address` to `nil`, because it would be already be defined and return early.

In these cases, you should reset it like this:

```rb
def reset_main_address_memoization
  self.send(:remove_instance_variable, :@main_address) if instance_variable_defined?(:@main_address)
end
```